# JQuery UI Autocompletar - "This source is not a function"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Estoy intentando usar la función `autocomplete` de `JQuery UI` para sugerir palabras previamente almacenadas en `localStorage`.

El problema es que no las sugiere pero si las guarda y a su vez cuando pruebo en consola me devuelve el `array` de objetos.

Éste es el método que guarda los datos ingresados a localStorage.

```
guardarSugerencias:function(cityName)
{       
    app.ciudades.ciudades.push({nombre:cityName});  
    localStorage.setItem("ciudades",JSON.stringify(app.ciudades));
},
```

y este el que se encarga de obtenerlos.

```
obtenerSugerencias:function()
{
    var results = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ciudades"));
    var search = $("#ciudad");
    $("#ciudad").on('focus',function()
    {
        search.autocomplete({
        source: results
    });     

    }); 
},
```

Cuando llamo a la función `obtenerSugerencias` en el `document.ready` me da ese error que dice:

> this source is not a function

Comment: Mil disculpas, colgué en contestar, hacía tiempo que no entraba, de hecho, hace un tiempo de esto pero no me funcionó en el archivo en el que la tenía que usar sinó que creé un archivo nuevo y probé ahí el autocompletar y si funcionó, no sé qué habrá pasado la verdad, muchas gracias y de nuevo te pido disculpas por la demora.

Answer (score 1):

### Problema:

- La opción [`source`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), cuando se indica un `array` espera que el mismo tenga uno de los siguientes formatos:

> - Un `array` de `strings`. Ejemplo `["Choice1", "Choice2"]`
> - Un `array` de objetos con las propiedades `label` y `value`. Ejemplo: `[{ label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

Y en realidad de le estas pasando un objeto: `{ciudades: [{nombre: ""},...]}`

### Solución:

Ya que no posees más que el nombre de la ciudad, lo mejor seria pasar un `array de strings`.

Ejemplo:

```
obtenerSugerencias:function()
{
  var results = [];
  var cities = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ciudades"));
  // Convertimos a un array de strings
  $.each(cities.ciudades, function(idx, city) {
    results.push(city.nombre);
  });

  var search = $("#ciudad");
  search.on('focus',function(){
    search.autocomplete({
    source: results //<-- pasamos un array de strings
  });     

  }); 
},
```